# Building an out-of-tree Linux kernel module in a separate object directory

Tags: makefile, linux-kernel, kbuild

I'm confronting the Linux kernel build system (Kbuild, kernel ≥2.6.28) with the directory structure and build system for a larger project. Our project contains an out-of-tree Linux kernel module, and our directory structure looks like this (simplified, obviously):

```
checkout/src/common/*.c           source files (common to Linux and other platforms)
checkout/src/linux-driver/*.c     source files (for the Linux kernel driver)
checkout/build/linux/Kbuild       Kbuild
tmp/linux-2.6.xx/                 where the Linux kernel is unpacked and configured
output/linux-arm-debug/           where object files must end up
```

The build process must not modify anything under `checkout`, and building the module must not modify anything under `tmp/linux-2.6.xx`. All output files must end up under `output/linux-arm-debug` (or whatever architecture and debug variant was selected at build time).

I've read [`kbuild/modules.txt`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt), and started to write my `Kbuild` file:

```
MOD_OUTPUT_DIR = ../../../output/linux-$(ARCH)-$(DEBUG)
obj-m += $(MOD_OUTPUT_DIR)/foo_mod.o
$(MOD_OUTPUT_DIR)/our_module-objs := $(MOD_OUTPUT_DIR)/foo_common.o $(MOD_OUTPUT_DIR)/foo_linux.o
```

This handles storing the object files in a different directory from where `Kbuild` lives. Now how can I specify that `foo_common.o` needs to be compiled from `…/checkout/src/common/foo_common.c` and `foo_linux.o` from `…/checkout/src/linux-driver/foo_linux.c`?

Answer (score 13):

Here is a Makefile which does out of source-tree builds for out of kernel-tree modules (adapted from @Mark's comment)...

```
KDIR ?= /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
BUILD_DIR ?= $(PWD)/build
BUILD_DIR_MAKEFILE ?= $(PWD)/build/Makefile

default: $(BUILD_DIR_MAKEFILE)
    make -C $(KDIR) M=$(BUILD_DIR) src=$(PWD) modules

$(BUILD_DIR):
    mkdir -p "$@"

$(BUILD_DIR_MAKEFILE): $(BUILD_DIR)
    touch "$@"

clean:
    make -C $(KDIR) M=$(BUILD_DIR) src=$(PWD) clean
```

Note: You still need a Kbuild file...

```
obj-m += my_driver.o
```

Comment: I didnot understand why we still need a Kbuild file `obj-m += my_driver.o`

Comment: It is just a matter of preference. If you want you can add this line to the Makefile. Putting it in the Kbuild file simplifies the Makefile by removing the `ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)` test used to guard this statement in the Makefile. See: http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-2-sect-4.shtml

Comment: This is so very close to what I need, but sadly it assumes that the module `Makefile` is in the `src` directory, which is not the case for me (it's being built by autoconf, so `Makefile.in` is in the source and `Makefile` in the build/M dir, and likewise for the Kbuild files).

Comment: I would feel better about this if `src=` were documented in `modules.txt` :-(

Comment: Yes, I know this is several years old, but the issue of what `src=` is doing I feel is an important one.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. I modified `linux_2_6_34/scripts/Makefile.build` as follows.

```
ifdef SRCDIR
src := $(SRCDIR)
else
src := $(obj)
endif
```

`SRCDIR` is the directory source.

To compile the module, run

```
make -c $(KDIR) M=$(Your_output_dir) SRCDIR=$(your source directory)`
```

Comment: So close - the c-files compiled, but it refuses to take the final step to generate the `.ko` (version 3.14.0)

Comment: Sorry - pebcak - had a bug in my Kbuild - this does the trick - with the proviso that it gets a little confused about which directory and at one stage requires the Kbuild file to be in both directories.  That's a small price to pay to get it going

Comment: This seems to work but for some reason I need to have an empty Makefile in the output directory for this to work (linux-4.1.6)

Comment: I got it to work without modifying `Makefile.build` or any other files: 

`make -C /path/to/linux-3.16.1/build M=/path/to/module/build src=/path/to/module`. 

I don't know whether this will work with any other versions of the kernel, but perhaps it will. I did still need `touch Makefile` in the build dir.

Comment: @Mark for cross compilation, can I write the `Makefile` same as above specified. If so, where I need to specify the cross compiler options. BTW I want to cross compile with arm-eabi-gcc

Comment: @AbdulGafoor Not sure what you're referring to "...as above specified". Jegan is modifying a kernel makefile. If you're going to do that, not much reason to do what I did. If you don't want to modify  kernel makefiles, create `Makefile` and `Kbuild` as in Example 2, Section 3.2, https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt - this is what I did. Then (IIRC) you'd specify cross-compile opts when invoking make on `Makefile`, and it would pass them on so Kbuild would see them. Hopefully that works, but I'm rusty on cross-compiling.

Answer (score 2):

My inelegant but effective solution is to copy the source files into the output tree.

```
FOO_SOURCES_DIR = $(src)/../../../checkout/src
FOO_MOD_OUTPUT_DIR = ../../../output/linux-$(ARCH)-$(DEBUG)

# Specify the object files
obj-m += $(FOO_MOD_OUTPUT_DIR)/foo_mod.o
FOO_MODULE_OBJS := $(FOO_MOD_OUTPUT_DIR)/foo_common.o $(FOO_MOD_OUTPUT_DIR)/foo_linux.o
$(FOO_MOD_OUTPUT_DIR)/foo_mod-objs := $(FOO_MODULE_OBJS)

# Where to find the sources
$(src)/$(FOO_MOD_OUTPUT_DIR)/foo_common.c: $(FOO_SOURCES_DIR)/common/foo_common.c
$(src)/$(FOO_MOD_OUTPUT_DIR)/foo_linux.c: $(FOO_SOURCES_DIR)/linux-driver/foo_linux.c

# Rules to copy the sources
FOO_COPIED_SOURCES = $(patsubst %.o,$(src)/%.c,$(FOO_MODULE_OBJS))
$(FOO_COPIED_SOURCES):
        $(Q)mkdir -p $(@D)
        cp -f $< $@
clean-files += $(FOO_COPIED_SOURCES)
clean-dirs += $(FOO_MOD_OUTPUT_DIR)
```

Comment: Copy? At least make symbolic links _once_ and then leave it be!

Comment: @Shahbaz Symbolic links don't always work in build trees. They tend to be included as symlinks in archivers. I even had to work on Samba exports at some point (ugh). Copying a handful of source files in a Linux kernel build tree is peanuts.

Answer (score 1):

While you haven't mentioned what you've tried so far (or whether you found a solution already), it looks like you just need to continue further down the [modules.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/kbuild/modules.html#several-subdirectories) file a bit -- to **Section 4.3**:

```
--- 4.3 Several Subdirectories

kbuild can handle files that are spread over several directories.
Consider the following example:

.
|__ src
|   |__ complex_main.c
|   |__ hal
|   |__ hardwareif.c
|   |__ include
|       |__ hardwareif.h
|__ include
    |__ complex.h

To build the module complex.ko, we then need the following
kbuild file:

    --> filename: Kbuild
    obj-m := complex.o
    complex-y := src/complex_main.o
    complex-y += src/hal/hardwareif.o

    ccflags-y := -I$(src)/include
    ccflags-y += -I$(src)/src/hal/include

As you can see, kbuild knows how to handle object files located
in other directories. The trick is to specify the directory
relative to the kbuild file's location. That being said, this
is NOT recommended practice.

For the header files, kbuild must be explicitly told where to
look. When kbuild executes, the current directory is always the
root of the kernel tree (the argument to "-C") and therefore an
absolute path is needed. $(src) provides the absolute path by
pointing to the directory where the currently executing kbuild
file is located.
```

Comment: I've read that part, and I'm at a loss as to how this helps me. In that example, `complex_main.c` and `complex_main.o` are in the same directory. In my build tree, sources and build products are completely separate.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but it looks like [O= flag](http://lwn.net/Articles/90818/) is what you need.

Comment: It does look right. I'd be surprised if I hadn't tried it, but it's been a while and I've moved on to other projects, so I can't honestly be sure. Thanks for your suggestion, I'll try to find the opportunity to try it.

Comment: Not working for me - it seems like `O=` and `KBUILD_OUTPUT` both need to be applied at the point where you build the kernel itself, not just the external modules.  What I see is errors finding generated files within the source tree - for example `linux/version.h` - its looking for them in the O= location.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the environment variable `KBUILD_OUTPUT`. This functions similar to the `O=` option; however, since it's an environment variable, it can span multiple makefiles where `O=` can't be passed or an out-of-directory module needs to be built.  I was having this same issue with trying to build a set of compat-wireless modules and I needed to use `O=` for the actual kernel image build.