# Out of tree kernel modules: Multiple module, single Makefile, same source file, different build options

Tags: makefile, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am building a set of Linux kernel modules using shared source code. From what I understand, the Makefile has to be named "Makefile" so I have to use the same Makefile to build two different modules. How can I build two different modules, within the same Makefile, with the same source code, but with two different build options?

For example, my modules are called module1 and module2. So I have the following line to define them:

```
obj-m := module1.o module2.o
```

Among other files, both module1 and module2 need to use the same source file `code.c`, but built with different build options. So say for example, the Makefile contains the following lines:

```
module1-objs = module1_code.o other_code.o
module2-objs = module2_code.o other_code.o
```

I want `module1_code.o` and `module2_code.o` to be built from code.c, but with different options. Specifically, I want one `module1_code.o` with a macro defined `-DPREPROCEFFOR_FLAG=1`, and `module2_code.o` built without the macro.

From what I understand, the system of Makefiles used in Linux implicitly infers that for an object file called "code.o", the source file is called "code.c", so how would I achieve this? Is is possible? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You can name your makefile anything you want. make will only look for [certain filenames](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Makefile-Arguments) by default though. For any other names you need to use the `-f` argument.

Comment: If you give make a specific rule for your object file with a prerequisite of the relevant source file and rules to build the target make will use that instead of the default rule you mentioned. So `module1_code.o: code.c ; <command to build>`.

Comment: Out of tree builds would also solve this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5718899/building-an-out-of-tree-linux-kernel-module-in-a-separate-object-directory

Answer (score 5):

You have a problem here, because you obviously have `code.c` being compiled differently when `-DPREPROCEFFOR_FLAG=1` is defined, but once it's compiled into `code.o`, make won't care about preprocessor flags or whatever because `code.o` will be already up to date.

You need a way to build `code.c` to different object files with different C flags. There's probably a clean way to do this (had no chance with `O=` for out of tree modules), but here's my innelegant yet effective solution for the moment:

```make
my_modules:
    cp code.c code_noflags.c
    cp code.c code_withflags.c
    make -C $$KDIR M=$$PWD modules
    rm code_noflags.c code_withflags.c

# module objects
obj-m := module1.o module2.o

# module1 specifics
module1-y := code_withflags.o
CFLAGS_code_withflags.o := -DPREPROCEFFOR_FLAG=1

# module2 specifics
module2-y := code_noflags.o
```

Just call:

```
$ make KDIR=/path/to/kernel
```

You can verify the preprocessor flag is passed to the source file for the right object with:

```
$ make KDIR=/path/to/kernel V=1 | grep PREPRO
```

You could also have two separate directories for each module, if this is possible, and have a symbolic link `code.c` in each one pointing to the common real `code.c`. However, this is still hackish and doesn't feel right.

Comment: A (potentially just as inelegant) solution would be to create a sim-link to code.c, i.e. code-link.c, and then compile the link file wit the alternative flag.

Answer (score 3):

One simple solution is, continuing from your Makefile

```
obj-m := module1.o module2.o

module1-objs = module1_code.o other_code.o
module2-objs = module2_code.o other_code.o
```

to add two more source files, module1_code.c and module2_code.c.

Then module1_code.c just looks like:

```
#define PREPROCEFFOR_FLAG 1
#include "code.c"
```

and module2_code.c is:

```
#include "code.c"
```

Or if you like, change the names in the Makefile and source files so that the second include without a define isn't necessary.  Also you could make the two source files nothing but an include and use the `CFLAGS_module1_code.o` variable to add the `-D...` option to the compiler if you prefer.

This is similar to what happens in the upstream kernel with `arch/x86/boot/video-vesa.c` and `arch/x86/realmode/rm/video-vesa.c` etc., where the realmode file just contains:

```
#include "../../boot/video-vesa.c"
```

and the video-vesa.c code ends up getting compiled twice with different compiler flags.

This seems preferable to copying the source files, since you end up with a mess there if you want to use the `O=...` option to the kernel build to keep a clean source tree and build in a separate object tree.