# Building an out-of-tree kernel module with separate source and build directories via autoconf

Tags: linux, makefile, linux-kernel, autoconf, kbuild

Given a package that uses autoconf (a configure script) to provide both a user-mode application and a kernel driver, with a directory structure like this:

```
configure.ac
configure
Makefile.am
user
    Makefile.am
    user.c
driver
    Makefile.am
    Kbuild.in
    driver.c
```

This successfully configures and builds both user and driver when configured locally (run `./configure --options`).

However a useful feature of configure scripts is that you can have a separate source and build directory, simply by running the script from the build directory, eg:

```
mkdir build && cd build && ../configure --options
```

This works fine for the user app, but I'm having trouble getting the kernel driver to build in this context.  In the driver's `Makefile.am` I have the following, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37858314/43534):

```
modules:
    $(MAKE) -C "$(LINUX_SOURCE_DIR)" M="@abs_builddir@" src="@abs_srcdir@" modules
```

But this fails to compile, as it's expecting the Kbuild or Makefile to be in `src`, but they're actually in `M`.  Omitting `src` does let it find the Kbuild but it then fails to find the actual source files (`no rule to make target //path/in/build//driver.o`).

Using `O=` as some other answers suggest is not correct, as this specifies the path to find the **kernel**'s output files (`.config` etc) and these are still in the `LINUX_SOURCE_DIR`.  (So trying to use it results in various other missing-file errors.)

I'm hoping for a solution that doesn't require modifying any actual Kbuild scripts, since those are outside my package's control.

Thus far the best option I've come up with is to copy/link all the module source files into the build directory before calling Kbuild, which is not ideal.  I'm hoping there's a hidden setting that can be used for this.

Comment: `Thus far the best option I've come up with is to copy/link all the module source files into the build directory before calling Kbuild` - I know no other way for out-of-source build of the kernel modules.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, oh, really? The above excerpt shows how to get it `make -C "$KERNEL_BUILD_DIR" M=$PWD modules`, if you want to compile module in $PWD for kernel which build files are located in $KERNEL_BUILD_DIR.

Comment: Did you try to remove `src="@abs_srcdir@"` from your *Makefile*?

Comment: @0andriy: In command line `make -C "$KERNEL_BUILD_DIR" M=$PWD modules` variable `KERNEL_BUILD_DIR` actually refers to kernel core build directory, which is actually a kernel source directory too. Option `M` refers to module's source dir, but **resulted files will be placed in this directory too**. So, there is no separation "module source dir" and "module build dir" here.