# cmake : specify linux kernel module output build directory

Tags: cmake, kbuild

Here is my cmake to build linux kernle hello world module.

```
if ( UNIX )
    # Version number
    set ( DRV_MAJOR 1 )
    set ( DRV_MINOR 0 )
    set ( DRV_PATCH 0 )

    set ( DRV_VERSION ${DRV_MAJOR}.${DRV_MINOR}.${DRV_PATCH} )

    configure_file( drv_config.h.cmake ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/drv_config.h )
    execute_process(COMMAND uname -r
                    OUTPUT_VARIABLE os_version
                    OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)

    set(module_path /lib/modules/${os_version})
    set(module_build_path ${module_path}/build)

    add_custom_command(OUTPUT drv.ko
                       COMMAND ${CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM} -C ${module_build_path} M=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
                       DEPENDS driver.c Kbuild
                       COMMENT "Building drv.ko"
                      )

    add_custom_target(drv ALL DEPENDS drv.ko)

endif( UNIX )
```

And my Kbuild :

```
obj-m += drv.o
drv-objs := driver.o
```

How can I specify the output directory for all object files and related stuff? For the moment build stuff is generated at the source directory location. And I'd like not to mix source and obj files. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you read the [CMake tutorial](https://cmake.org/cmake-tutorial/)?

Comment: Yes, I have. There is nothing about kernel module

Comment: But there is about `configure_file`.

Comment: There is no issue with configure_file in my case. I want all object files to be stored inside binary filder not src. Is it possible to do without copying it from source to bin ?

Answer (score 10):

This answer above helped me, figure it out.  If someone is curious upon how.

Check out it out and gitlab: 
https://gitlab.com/christophacham/cmake-kernel-module

In the end the cmake file looks like the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0 FATAL_ERROR)

project(driver VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES C)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

# Find kernel headers
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")
find_package(KernelHeaders REQUIRED)
include_directories(${KERNELHEADERS_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set(DRIVER_FILE hello.ko)
set(KBUILD_CMD ${CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM} -C ${KERNELHEADERS_DIR} modules M=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} src=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

# Generate the Kbuild file through cmake.
FILE(WRITE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Kbuild "obj-m := hello.o")

add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${DRIVER_FILE}
        COMMAND ${KBUILD_CMD}
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
        DEPENDS hello.c VERBATIM)

add_custom_target(driver ALL DEPENDS ${DRIVER_FILE})
```

This together with the FindKernelHeaders.cmake allowed me to build the kernel module with cmake in a build folder.
It was never meant to be shared, but was done anyway as there seems to be interest in this question.

Comment: If anyone wants to use CLion, I found that to stop the editor from complaining about ```MODULE_LICENSE``` and so on, you need to add ```add_definitions(-D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE)``` somewhere in your CMakeLists.txt I also had to add a dummy target: ```add_library(dummy_target hello.c)``` so it would parse the source file in the first place.

Comment: I had to modify `FindKernelHeaders.cmake` in order to find the header files on Ubuntu. Change line 11 to `PATHS /usr/src/linux-headers-${KERNEL_RELEASE}` (was `PATHS /usr/src/kernels/${KERNEL_RELEASE}`

Comment: I added all information + changes I had to make to fit my needs into a forked project. Thanks to Christoph Acham and MerseyViking for their constributions and ideas! https://gitlab.com/phip1611/cmake-kernel-module

Answer (score 0):

Referring to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37858314 it seems that a solution is:

```
COMMAND ${CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM} -C ${module_build_path} 
        M=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} src=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
```

Comment: Thanks, this almost worked for me, but the modpost stage gives an error saying that it cannot find `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Makefile`