# How to run Make and Kbuild to generate files in a specific directory?

Tags: linux, rust, makefile, linux-kernel

I am getting into writing Linux Kernel modules and know nothing about `Make` files.

I want to compile my code located in my `src` directory and place the files generated from running `Make` into a sibling `build` directory.

So if I have a directory structure like this:

```
my-mod-folder/
    src/
        main.rs
    build/
```

Then how should I write my `Kbuild` and `Makefile` so that I can generate a `build/rustmod.ko` from my `src/main.rs` file? And where should I place the `Kbuild` and `Makefile` - can I place them in the root of `my-mod-folder` and have that work?

Ideally I would like the structure to look like this:

```
my-mod-folder/
    src/
        main.rs
    build/
        rustmod.ko
      
    Kuild
    Makefile
```

I know these are noob questions so please bear with me as I get up to speed.

I currently have my `Kubild` and `Makefile` inside of the `src` directory and they compile my simple `main.rs` file correctly, but still place all the output files in the `src` directory.

Here is my current `src/Kbuild` file:

```
# SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0

obj-m := rustmod.o
rustmod-objs := main.o
```

And here is my current `src/Makefile`:

```
# SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0
KDIR ?= /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build

default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$$PWD

modules_install: default
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$$PWD modules_install
```

Also, I am using Rust here, but I have the Kernel set up correctly and can confirm that I can load my modules. So the `Kbuild` and `Makefile` are only what I need help with right now. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Building an out-of-tree Linux kernel module in a separate object directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5718899/building-an-out-of-tree-linux-kernel-module-in-a-separate-object-directory)